# using a usb battery as a ups for a nest cam?

Tags: battery, power, ups

So I was thinking about getting a [Nest Cam Indoor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nest_Labs#Nest_Cam_Indoor) but I'd like it to record even if the power goes out. I have my wireless router and cable modem plugged into UPS already and was wondering if an external battery pack (the [Jackery Titan](http://www.jackery.com/jackery-titan/) in particular) would serve as an effective UPS? Or do UPS's provide more functionality than USB batteries do?

I mean, for certain applications, a UPS is obviously gonna be better. A USB battery isn't gonna provide the wattage that a desktop or even a laptop would need. But a Nest Cam Indoor doesn't consume a ton of watts and it appears to be chargeable completely with USB.

I guess an analogous situation would be using a Raspberry Pi with a USB battery, altho the Nest Cam Indoor consumes less power (5VDC @ 1A vs 5.25VDC @ 2A).

Comment: Since it is USB powered it is far more efficient to use a USB power bank rather than a UPS which is normally very inefficient under low power loads. However, you would need to ensure that it can output power to connected devices when it is being charged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed Jackery and got the following response:

> All our batteries support pass through charging so as long as they are plugged in they will continue to provide power to connected devices. However when they not plugged in to a wall adaptor, then you need to press the power button manually to start charging.

The fact that a power button needs to be pressed makes it a bit ineffective as a UPS. There might be other brands that are better suited tho.